# Change jquery variable on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Its very basic question. I need your help. There is my variable

```
var total=$("#bhs").attr("value")*2;
$('div#coupon').append(total);
```

BUT I want to change the variable on the current page and reflect the result same time
how can I do that?

Thanks

it s kind of a bet slip

user input *2 = reflect same time results.

( text input ) (Result)

user inputs 3

jquery multiples 2

and shows the result near the textbox

Comment: Most of these answers are terrible. Use jQuery's trigger for live updating. If it sounds like an event driven feature, you should use events.

Comment: Awesome! Also, today I learned that the noise to signal ratio on SO has gotten very bad.

Comment: is it easy to learn that jquery ? i m new to this one.

Comment: @cemsitcan: Yes and no. Depends on your background.

Comment: @felix 1.5 month of php mysql and html,css background, i want to deploy a live betting site

Comment: @cemsitcan: Well, whatever tool you use you should obviously learn how to use it. You already use jQuery so I don't really understand why you are asking this (*is it easy to learn that jquery*)...

Comment: I also suggest you describe your problem better next. Updating a text box based on the input of another one is different than monitoring a *variable*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to update two input boxes in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681706/how-to-update-two-input-boxes-in-jquery)

Comment: @felix i mean "complete" learning it. otherhand i can deploy a site but its always has security flaws or other things that i didnt know.

Comment: @felix no no just one text box.. user inputs 4 and html show 8 then user clen the box enters 7 and html shows 14 .. its very easy but m stuck

Comment: @cemsitcan: textbox, element, does not make such a big difference. You can never * completely* learn something... you can only get better.

Comment: user inputs 4 html shows 8 user then change his mind enters 5 html shows 10 icant do that , :(

Comment: @felix .keydown() solved thanks

Comment: `$('#fly').val(_newValue_);`  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you probably want to dispatch a custom event via .[trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)() that listens for a change in the variable (via a setter function probably).

Comment: This sounds like a good solution. How would you go about checking for an update in the text box as the user types using this method?

Comment: The question didn't say anything about a textbox or how the variable is updated. This variable may be updated from many different places, such as an xhr, user input or something else. In the case of a textbox you can listen for key down or up events and handle it there.

Comment: user input *2 = reflect same time results.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value of "value" as such with jQuery:

```
$("#bhs").attr("value", total);
```

Comment: no its not updating the result at the same time. think about bet sites type bet stake and print the possible winnings

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the result? Can you post an html sample as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about updating a textbox, you'll need to poll for changes in the box using `setInterval`.

This way you'll be able to update the value as the user types, alternatively you could do the update in the `blur` event once the user exits the focus on the textbox.

Something like this:

```
setInterval(updateValueFromTextBox,200);

function updateValueFromTextBox()
{
var newNumber = $("textBox").attr("bla") * 2;
$("resultOnPage").html(newNumber);
}
```

or

```
$("textBox").blur(updateValueFromTextBox);
```

If you use the polling method, remember that polling for the lifetime of the page could be a bit costly. More likely you'll want to start polling on `focus` of the textbox and stop polling on `blur`.

Comment: Nope, he can dispatch a custom event, no need to poll. Polling a variable for the life of the page? Heh.

Comment: Custom event sounds good. He wouldn't really have to poll for the life of the page tho. He could simply put the poll inside the focus event and detach it in the blur event.

Comment: A poll is a terrible solution 99% of the time and 100% of the time for this question.

Comment: no need to setinterval, i want bwin.com like betslip

Comment: Perhaps i've misunderstood the queestion. I thought you wanted to update the page as the user types numbers into a box....in realtime.

Comment: yes it is... exactly. tigger looks good for this job

Answer (score 0):

```
var total=$("#bhs").attr("value")*2;
$("#coupon").html(total);
```

Comment: no it dont worked, think about betting slip

Answer (score 0):

This should take the value of #bhs, multiply it by two, and then place the total in the coupon div.

```
var total = Number($("#bhs").attr("value")) * 2;
$("div#coupon").html(total);
```

Comment: Using the Number object directly is pretty much always a bad idea...

Comment: but it is not updating it in real time